# EF4 and MVC3 mapping ViewModels to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an EF4 Entity Workgroup. Below is the meta-data for that model for reference.

```
    [MetadataType(typeof(WorkgroupMetaData))]
public partial class Workgroup {
    public Contact manager { get; set; }
}

[Bind(Exclude = "id")]
public class WorkgroupMetaData
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Org. Number")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Org. Number is required.")]
    public string org_number { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Workgroup Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Workgroup name is required.")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Customer Contact")]
    public int customer_contact_id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Manager")]
    public int manager_id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Tech. Lead")]
    public int lead_id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Time Approver")]
    public int time_approver { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Description")]
    public string description { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public object created_at { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public object last_modified_at { get; set; }
}
```

I've got a ViewModel defined as:

```
    public class WorkgroupViewModel
{
    public Workgroup Workgroup { get; set; }
    public List<Workgroup> Workgroups { get; set; }
}
```

On the view I have a grid to dump out the workgroups available. This works but I was wondering how to convert the ID fields to the actual strings from another table. Basically the manager, customer_contact, lead are all references to the Contact entity. I would like to show the names from Contacts instead of just the id.

How can this be accomplished? I've looked around a bit but I can't seem to find a suggestion or an answer. Maybe I looking at this from the wrong perspective?

Comment: Lookup AutoMapper to see if it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using a wrapper around Workgroup (decorator pattern) or Tuple or creating a custom class that binds them together.

```
public class WorkgroupDisplayModel
{
    public Workgroup Workgroup { get; set; }
    public Manager Manager { get; set; }
    // Add additional properties for each related type
}
```

In your EF query you can do something like:

```
var query = from w in Context.Workgroups
            join m in Context.Managers
                on w.manager_id equals m.uid
            // Additional joins for each related table
            where w.Description == "Project 1" // Whatever criteria
            select Tuple.Create(w, m); // Add param for each type
            //or
            //select new WorkgroupDisplayModel { Workgroup = w, Manager = m, ... };
var list = query.ToList();
var contact = list[0].Item1; // Tuple has strongly typed Item1 thru ItemN
var manager = list[0].Item2;
```

Then your view model could have:

```
List<Tuple<Workgroup, Manager, Customer, Lead>> Workgroups { get; set; }
```

or

```
List<WorkgroupDisplayModel> Workgroups { get; set; }
```

Comment: Oh... instead of actual types you can also use strings for Manager, Customer, etc.  Then the query syntax would be:  select Tuple.Create(w, m.Name, c.LastFirst, l.DomainName) or the like...